# Select another column with coalesce on second column

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and pyodbc.

I have the following query, which is part of a stored procedure:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT a.Answer_Value
                FROM Answer as a
                WHERE
                    a.UserId = u.UserId
                    AND a.SurveyId = <SURVEY_ID>
                    AND a.QuestionId = <QUESTION_ID>
            ), -1) AS ANS_Q<QUESTION_ID>
```

This returns a.Answer_Value for every Question_Id and returns -1 if the user has not answered that question. I would like to select the Question_Id as well to display in the table such as

```
SELECT COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT a.Answer_Value, **a.Question_Id**
                FROM Answer as a
                WHERE
                    a.UserId = u.UserId
                    AND a.SurveyId = <SURVEY_ID>
                    AND a.QuestionId = <QUESTION_ID>
            ), -1) AS ANS_Q<QUESTION_ID>
```

I would like to display:

```
QuestionId   Answer_Value
1            3
2            5
3           -1
```

This returns the error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. How can I display multiple values while keeping the coalesce function on Answer_Value?

Thank you.

My tables are as follows:

[image]

[image]
(test output for comment below)

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT q.QuestionId, COALESCE(a.Anwer_Value, -1) as Anwer_Value
FROM Question as q
    left join Answer as a ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
```

This will return all of the QuestionIds existing in Question table and corresponding Answer_Values if exist, otherwise returns -1 .

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding. I've tried this and it still does not return the -1 values for questions with no answer. I've also tried isnull, which also does not work. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Hi @RinaTse! Does it return Anwer_Values for questions with answer? And, also, what it returns for questions without answer, nothing or maybe empty string?
Could you please run the query and paste the result here, if it's possible?

Comment: It returns the Answer_Values for questions with answers and nothing for the questions without an answer. I've included the output of this in the question above. Thank you

Comment: Interesting. We need to find a table where all questions stored and then left join that table with "Answer" table. I thought the Question table is the one we need. What about "SurveyStructure", whats in that table?